# cómo puedo aparecer o desaparecer el botón editar de la columna GridViewCommandColumn en devexpress según un valor devuelto en mi consulta

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, visual-studio-2010

Por favor como podría aparecer o desaparecer el botón 'Edit' de la columna GridViewCommandColumn, por ejemplo si es 1 que aparece y si es 0 desaparece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esto de resuelve la visibilidad en la columna de comandos para que dependiendo del valor aparece o desaparece el boton edit

```
Protected Sub grvProveedorVehiculo_CommandButtonInitialize(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewCommandButtonEventArgs) Handles grvProveedorVehiculo.CommandButtonInitialize
        If (e.VisibleIndex = -1) Then Return
        Select Case e.ButtonType
            Case ColumnCommandButtonType.Edit
                e.Visible = EditButtonVisibleCriteria(grvProveedorVehiculo, e.VisibleIndex)
                ' break;
                'Case ColumnCommandButtonType.Delete
                '    e.Visible = DeleteButtonVisibleCriteria(grvProveedorVehiculo, e.VisibleIndex)
                '    ' break;
        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Function EditButtonVisibleCriteria(grid As ASPxGridView, visibleIndex As Integer) As Boolean
        'Dim keyValue As Integer = CInt(grid.GetRowValues(visibleIndex, grid.KeyFieldName))
        Dim icono As String = CInt(grid.GetRowValues(visibleIndex, "icono"))
        If icono = 0 Then
            'Return keyValue Mod 2 <> 0
            Return 0
        Else
            Return 1
        End If


    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

En C# iniciando la pantalla (Page_Load).-

```
  if(valor == 0)
   {
    ((GridViewCommandColumn) GRILLA.Columns[0]).UpdateButton.Visible = false;
    ((GridViewCommandColumn) GRILLA.Columns[0]).DeleteButton.Visible = false;
    ((GridViewCommandColumn) GRILLA.Columns[0]).NewButton.Visible = false;
   }
```